# How are you supposed to get up the last room before the boss in the water temple?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

The second-to-last room of the water temple features a slanted floor with 3 sliding spike things going across. You have to get to the top.

After you get about a third of the way up, your upwards progress slows to a crawl. It's almost inevitable that one of the sliding spike things is going to stab you, which makes you slide to the bottom (usually hitting all the sliding spike things you've already passed to that point).

I eventually decided to just go with the speed-running strategy I'd seen for that part, which is to L-target away from the ramp and run up backwards. (Still took a few tries even doing this.)

Then I died to the boss and had to try this room again, and was able to (accidentally) make it up going forward. For the sake of future runs, **what is the actual timing for going up the proper (forward-facing) way**? **Where do I have to stand**, and **where should the sliding things be**, to guarantee that I make it up safely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stand as far to the right as you can. When the bottom [Blade Trap](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Blade_Trap) hits the right wall, begin running straight forward. You should make it to the top.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is stand closer to the right wall and wait for the bottom spike to be just passing to the left in front of me and then I close my eyes while walking straight forward. It may be silly and I don't know why but it always works for me if I don't watch:D 
Note: If you stand too close to the right wall the small pillar at the top will send you sliding back down.